# Access JSON property on same object definition

Tags: javascript, json

I need to know how to access properties inside an object in the same property definition using JSON format in JavaScript, like this:

```
var myobj = {
    DateToday: getDate(),
    DatePast: DateToday - 1
}
```

When I create objects in this way, the browser throws the error `"DateToday" is not defined`.

Comment: Is your code JavaScript or JSON? It is definitly not JSON, so why are you talking about JSON?

Comment: I'm coding JavaScript and using JSON as the format for object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't. You'll need to make DatePast a function, like so:

```
var myobj = {
    Date: getDate(),
    DatePast: function(){ this.Date - 1 };
}
```

Then you'd access DatePast using:

```
myobj.DatePast();
```

Alternatively, if Date will never changes, you could use:

```
var myobj = {
    Date: getDate(),
    DatePast: getDate() - 1
}
```

Then you could access it like so:

```
myobj.DatePast
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because it's not in memory yet for reference. You need to do this:

```
var myobj = {
    DateToday: getDate()
}

myobj.DatePast= myobj.DateToday - 1;
```